# In Unreal-Engine 4 is there a way to stop a flipbook after it has completed its animation?

Tags: 2d, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am trying to destroy a flipbook when it has ended its animation in unreal engine 4 (2d). However, I can't seem to find a way to stop a flipbook animation can you help.

Is there a way to stop a flipbook after it has animated?

I'm a bit new to unreal and I looked everywhere in options. Is this something I have to do programmatically with graphs?

Answer (score 1):

Here I have an example of my implementation, I know it's too late but I hope it helps you

```
void AHeroCharacter::UpdateAnimation(){
   const FVector PlayerVelocity = GetVelocity();
   const float PlayerSpeedSqr = PlayerVelocity.SizeSquared();
   const int32 PlaybackPositionInFrames = GetSprite()->GetPlaybackPositionInFrames();
   const int32 FlipbookLengthInFrames = GetSprite()->GetFlipbookLengthInFrames();
   UPaperFlipbook* DesiredAnimation;

   if (GetCharacterMovement()->IsFalling()) {
        DesiredAnimation = JumpAnimation;
        GetSprite()->SetFlipbook(DesiredAnimation);
        if (PlaybackPositionInFrames == FlipbookLengthInFrames - 1) GetSprite()->Stop();
        return;
   }

   GetSprite()->Play();
   if (PlayerSpeedSqr > 0.0f) {
        DesiredAnimation = RunningAnimation;
        GetSprite()->SetFlipbook(DesiredAnimation);
   }
   else {
       DesiredAnimation = IdleAnimation;
       GetSprite()->SetFlipbook(DesiredAnimation);
   }
}
```